# How do I iterate over multiple arrays/lists in a batch script simultaneously?

Tags: windows, list, batch-file

I want to set level, environment and version using three environment variables to run a test multiple times with different lvl, env and ver.
I already have three environment variables(array/list) from where I can read all three values to be set.

I want to iterate over three lists to get lvl, env and ver simultaneously.
I want it to be LVL1, ENV1, VER1 for first run then LVL2, ENV2, VER2 for next and so on.

I have these set in command window from where I will be launching my process

```
set LVL_VAR=LVL1 LVL2 LVL3
set ENV_VAR=ENV1 ENV2 ENV3
set VER_VAR=VER1 VER2 VER3
```

I can read these three to get lvl, env, ver
Then I need to set variables LVL, ENV and VER as LVL1, ENV1 and VER1 and so on before running RunTest.bat

This is what i tried, nested loop, but i dont know how to restrict 2nd and 3rd loop to set it correctly or if there is another way to do it.

```
@echo OFF
for %%L in (%LVL_VAR%) do call :for_lvl %%L
    
exit /b

:for_lvl
    set LVL=%1
    echo LVL %LVL%
    for %%E in (%ENV_VAR%) do call :for_env %%E
    exit /b
    goto :cont
  :cont
exit /b

:for_env
    set ENV=%1
    echo ENV %ENV%
    for %%V in (%VER_VAR%) do call :for_ver %%V
    goto :cont
  :cont
    exit /b
exit /b

:for_ver
    set VER=%1
    echo VER %VER%
    echo =======================RunTest.bat===================
exit /b
```

The obvious output i get is

```
LVL LVL1
ENV ENV1
VER VER1
=======================RunTest.bat===================
VER VER2
=======================RunTest.bat===================
VER VER3
=======================RunTest.bat===================
ENV ENV2
VER VER1
=======================RunTest.bat===================
VER VER2
=======================RunTest.bat===================
VER VER3
=======================RunTest.bat===================
ENV ENV3
VER VER1
=======================RunTest.bat===================
VER VER2
=======================RunTest.bat===================
VER VER3
=======================RunTest.bat===================
LVL LVL2
ENV ENV1
VER VER1
=======================RunTest.bat===================
VER VER2
=======================RunTest.bat===================
VER VER3
=======================RunTest.bat===================
ENV ENV2
VER VER1
=======================RunTest.bat===================
VER VER2
=======================RunTest.bat===================
VER VER3
=======================RunTest.bat===================
ENV ENV3
VER VER1
=======================RunTest.bat===================
VER VER2
=======================RunTest.bat===================
VER VER3
=======================RunTest.bat===================
LVL LVL3
ENV ENV1
VER VER1
=======================RunTest.bat===================
VER VER2
=======================RunTest.bat===================
VER VER3
=======================RunTest.bat===================
ENV ENV2
VER VER1
=======================RunTest.bat===================
VER VER2
=======================RunTest.bat===================
VER VER3
=======================RunTest.bat===================
ENV ENV3
VER VER1
=======================RunTest.bat===================
VER VER2
=======================RunTest.bat===================
VER VER3
=======================RunTest.bat===================
```

I need it to be like this

```
LVL LVL1
ENV ENV1
VER VER1
=======================RunTest.bat===================
LVL LVL2
ENV ENV2
VER VER2
=======================RunTest.bat===================
LVL LVL3
ENV ENV3
VER VER3
=======================RunTest.bat===================
```

How do I limit my iterations or is there other way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Arrays, linked lists and other data structures in cmd.exe (batch) script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution for the task according to the description would be:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "LVL_VAR=LVL1 LVL2 LVL3"
set "ENV_VAR=ENV1 ENV2 ENV3"
set "VER_VAR=VER1 VER2 VER3"
(for /L %%I in (1,1,3) do call :RunTest %%I) & exit /B
:RunTest
for /F "tokens=%1" %%J in ("%LVL_VAR%") do set "LVL=%%J"
for /F "tokens=%1" %%J in ("%ENV_VAR%") do set "ENV=%%J"
for /F "tokens=%1" %%J in ("%VER_VAR%") do set "VER=%%J"
echo LVL %LVL%
echo ENV %ENV%
echo VER %VER%
echo =======================RunTest.bat===================
goto :EOF
```

The four `echo` command lines should be replaced by `call RunTest.bat`. It is also possible to include the code of `RunTest.bat` in this batch file after the three `for /F` loops replacing the four `echo` command lines and perhaps even `goto :EOF` for reducing the file system accesses on running this batch file.

There can be also used a different delimiter instead of a space in case of the three values of the three environment variables contain itself spaces like a horizontal tab character or a vertical bar as shown below:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "LVL_VAR=LVL1|LVL2|LVL3"
set "ENV_VAR=ENV1|ENV2|ENV3"
set "VER_VAR=VER1|VER2|VER3"
(for /L %%I in (1,1,3) do call :RunTest %%I) & exit /B
:RunTest
for /F "tokens=%1 delims=|" %%J in ("%LVL_VAR%") do set "LVL=%%J"
for /F "tokens=%1 delims=|" %%J in ("%ENV_VAR%") do set "ENV=%%J"
for /F "tokens=%1 delims=|" %%J in ("%VER_VAR%") do set "VER=%%J"
echo LVL %LVL%
echo ENV %ENV%
echo VER %VER%
echo =======================RunTest.bat===================
```

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `call /?`
- `echo /?`
- `exit /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Answer (score 0):

*Lists* and *arrays* are very different things. These are lists:

```
set LVL_VAR=LVL1 LVL2 LVL3
set ENV_VAR=ENV1 ENV2 ENV3
set VER_VAR=VER1 VER2 VER3
```

You can convert lists into arrays this way:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set n=0
for %%a in (%LVL_VAR%) do set /A n+=1 & set "LVL[!n!]=%%a"
set n=0
for %%a in (%ENV_VAR%) do set /A n+=1 & set "ENV[!n!]=%%a"
set n=0
for %%a in (%VER_VAR%) do set /A n+=1 & set "VER[!n!]=%%a"
rem Keep here the last value of %n%
```

... and then process the three arrays at same time via the subscript or index:

```
for /L %%i in (1,1,%n%) do (
   echo LVL !LVL[%%i]!
   echo ENV !ENV[%%i]!
   echo VER !VER[%%i]!
   echo =======================RunTest.bat===================
)
```

I suggest you to review [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990)